# Perl module for making TKX Chart

Tags: perl, charts, tcl, tkx

Is there any perl module for making chart in TKX.

atleast any options for image based chart shall also be OK

Comment: I'm afraid your question is a bit too vague to give a meaningful answer. Please take a look at [ask] for some detail on what makes a good question.

Comment: It's not Tkx but you can check http://search.cpan.org/~djibel/Tk-Chart-1.16/lib/Tk/Chart.pm

Answer (score 1):

No; at least nothing stood out in a [CPAN search](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Tkx). Tkx makes it easy to call through to Tcl code, though, so you could use a [Tcl chart](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9503) library.